# How to save Tables values to Jquery Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to update a row using jQuery Ajax.

I have successfully change the column from table `<tr>` to `<input type="text">`, but I am unable to save the updated column values to jQuery variables, so that i can send the updated data to server.

Kindly guide me how to save the updated values in Variables

```js
 var editing = false;
 $(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {

   if (!editing) {
     editing = true;
     $(this).closest('tr').find('.edited').each(function() {
       var html = $(this).html();
       var input = $('<input type="text" />');
       input.val(html);
       $(this).html(input);

     });
   }

 }).change(function() {

   editing = false;
   // var username= 

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class=" table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">Username</td>
      <td class="id edited">Password</td>
      <td class="id edited">Role</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- ROW 2 -->

    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">UsernameText</td>
      <td class="id edited">PasswordText</td>
      <td class="id edited">RoleText</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery Variables in this context?

Comment: I want to store values in variables so that i can send the updated values to database

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are updating the HTML with the *jQuery Object* `input`, which you need to use `.append()` or similar.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.edited').each(function () {
  var html = $(this).html();
  var input = $('<input type="text" />');
  input.val(html);
  input.appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) , but still i am unable to understand how to save the values in a variables..This code is adding another input field in the table.